# Как проверить наличие/отсутствие роли?

Tags: python, discord.py

Бот не должен банить тех людей, у которых есть определённая роль.

Как проверить, что пользователь НЕ имеет роль, и ему можно выдать бан?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
member = объект участника
role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id='айди роли')
if role not in member.roles:
    pass
```